# Play framework - slow csv transfer rate

Tags: java, networking, playframework

created a chart with play framework 1.2.3 to show the CPU/Memory of a few servers.

To make the chart, I've created a CSV file with all the information. This CSV is about 1.29MB.

My problem is the slow transfer between the server where the play framework is configured and my computer. It took about 22 seconds to transfer the file. If I copy a file directly, I get about 1.5Mb/s! This make that the chart takes about 30 seconds to show the data.

Name      Method  Status  Type      Initiator              size   Time
data.csv  GET     200 OK  text/csv  jquery-1.7.1.min.js:5  1.29M  25.17s

It is possible to enhance this transfer rate?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to zip and upload the file. 
Pls show the method which copies the uploaded file.